# PHPUnit ExpectOutputString failure shows binary output that is difficult to read

Tags: php, phpunit, phpstorm

I am writing code that outputs strings that include non-printing characters such as ESCAPE (\033).  If I use PHPUnit expectOutputString without the escape character and it fails, then it easy to read:

```
public function test_output() {

    echo "foo";
    $this->expectOutputString("foob");
}
```

This will fail and show me:

```
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
Expected :'foob'
Actual   :'foo'
```

Which is easy to debug, but when I have a string that includes an ESCAPE character:

```
public function test_escape_output() {
    echo "\033[0m";
    $this->expectOutputString("\033[0mm");
}
```

...and it fails, it shows me binary output:

```
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
Expected :Binary String: 0x1b5b306d6d
Actual   :Binary String: 0x1b5b306d
```

Which is hard to debug, once the strings start to get complex and long.

This seems to have changed in one of the recent upgrades to PhpStorm, I am currently running 2016.1.2.  Earlier, if it showed me the failure it would just hide the escape sequencing, but show the rest of the characters in standard output, so in the case of the "\033[0m", it would display ".[0m" (or actually the square-like character where I have the .").  Anyway, that was much easier to debug, because I was mostly interested in the printable characters.

I can't seem to find any way to ask PHPUnit to display it differently, or PhpStorm.  I'm also not clear why this distinction is drawn. HELP!

Comment: try using `echo pack("H*" , "\033[0m")` in `test_escape_output`

Comment: @CarlosCarucce - thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately, phpunit responds with:  pack(): Type H: illegal hex digit, which I think is referring to the escape character

Answer (score 0):

OK, so after fussing with this for sometime, I ended up using PHPUnit test doubles to fix this problem.

In the class being tested, I funnel all the escape sequences into one method. Then create a stub for that method to use callback to another function that replaces all escape characters with escaped \e so it becomes a regular character (instead of triggering PHPStorm to show the whole string in binary).

Then I can compare the expected output as normal strings, and PHPStorm shows me the strings in normal text instead of binary, making life a lot easier during debugging.

```
class EscapeStrings {

    // the method that all output is sent through, so it can be stubbed
    public function output($text) {
        echo $text;
    }
}

class testClass extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    // replace the escape character with a printable \\e character
    public function printableEscape($text) {
        return str_replace("\e","\\e",$text);
    }

    public function testOutput() {

        // create a mock
        $stub = $this->createMock(EscapeStrings::class);

        // switch the output method to call the printable escape method with the $text parameter
        $stub->method('output')
            ->will($this->returnCallback([$this,'printableEscape']));


        // now can do normal string compare and easier debugging
        $this->assertEquals("\\e[0mHello", $stub->output("\e[0mHello"));
    }

}
```